# Python urllib.request - no module named request

Tags: python-requests

I've read through many similar posts but none solve my problem.  When trying to import requests I get a response saying no module named request.

Fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04
I've installed pip3
I've installed requests

Here is the latest output :

> binx@Binx:~/Python$ sudo pip3 install requests --upgrade
>
> Downloading/unpacking requests from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/r/requests/requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=564fb256f865a79f977e57b79d31659a
>     Downloading requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (470kB): 470kB downloaded
>   Installing collected packages: requests
>     Found existing installation: requests 2.2.1
>       Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
>   Successfully installed requests
>   Cleaning up...
>
> binx@Binx:~/Python$ python connect.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "connect.py", line 7, in 
>      import urllib.request
>
> ImportError: No module named request
>
> binx@Binx:~/Python$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be best if you could show the code of your connect.py file.

From what I see now I'd guess that you're running python 2.x because only in python3 urllib was split to urllib.request. Find out what version is being ran after typing 'python' into terminal and try to use 'python3' instead.

Also I see you're new here so don't forget to accept answer as correct if someone posts correct answer.

Comment: I created a Python script under windows for a project I'm working on.  The script works just great however I felt the need to get off Windows and onto Ubuntu.  Now everything is broken.  I'll try to paste the code - hope I do it correctly

Comment: And you are correct - I ran Python and it displayed 2.7.6.  When I typed python3 connect.py the script ran fine. (well mostly but I'll tweak it).  Thank you